# Remove an element from an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I try to use `localStorage` and for that, I send once the `json` file to the client, and do all the logic using that file, but, because it shows in the `html`, I used this trick:

```
<script id="scr">
    var object = {value: {{ json_encode(temps) }} };
    localStorage.setItem("temps", JSON.stringify(object));
</script>
 ....
 some html
 ....
<script>
$( "#scr" ).remove();
</script>
```

The json get removed, but not if I do 'show page source',

So how do I hide the json file, while making only one request to the server?

Comment: The "view source" facility shows what the page looked like when it was loaded. You cannot control that.

Comment: so only ajax with lot of requests, or making the localstorage using what is already in the html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to make sure that the user cant see the JSON there is no way you can send it to the user and store it in localStorage without the user having access to it if he/she would like to.

But to make sure it doesn't show up in the html source you could always send a AJAX request to the server, which receives the JSON and then stores it in localStorage. That way it wont show up in the source.

But as I already said, if you want access to it in your client side javascript, the user can always get access to it if they would like to. So this is not recommended if the JSON data is sensitive.

Comment: How about saving to localStorage after the element will show, so it will be accessible after the server renders the html, because in the beginning I planed to send the json, and then retrieve the informations from it.

Comment: @Abdelouahab I don't really understand what you mean by that. What you are doing seems to be working, but there is no way to make sure it doesn't show up in the source, except for loading it through AJAX.

Comment: I mean, that in the past, I wanted to save to json, and then build the html from that json file, but now, I will do the inverse, I will build the html, and then from that html, I will make the localstorage

Comment: You could always send the JSON with a cookie set on the server (make sure it is not a HTTPOnly cookie), and then read the cookie data with javascript. Then it will not show up in the HTML source.

Comment: that json is too big to get inside the cookie, and the cookie will always get sent and received, I try to make the cookie the smallest i can

Comment: In that case I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. Remember you could always delete the cookie with javascript as soon as you have it saved in localstorage. That way it wont have to be sent back to the server. (That is of course unless the server sets it again).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible for you to hide the div, all browsers provide the source code, and tell us how it is that the browser interpret it step by step.
And localStorage is visible always you cant hide it
[image]

Comment: yes, there is also the `ressources` tab from chrome  dev, but since the data was not sensible, I was just hiding it from beginner, advanced users will always get the way to it since it is a normal http ...